# validate each incoming request

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture

I have two base classes `RequestBase` and `ResponseBase`, for request and response respectively. All types of requsets and response derived  from these classes. The `RequestBase` contains `ClientKey` and `AccessToken` fields. Also, I have the `AuthenticationService` service.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
   [OperationContract]
   public LoginResponse Login(LoginRequest request);
   ... other methods
}
```

Suppose we have the `OrderService` service.

```
public class OrderService:IOrderService
{       
   public OrderResponse GetOrders(OrderRequest request)
   {
      ...
   }       
}
```

I need to validate each request for `ClientKey` and `AccessToken`, also check whether the user is authenticated. I can do the following:

```
public OrderResponse GetOrders(OrderRequest request)
{
   var response = new OrderResponse(request.RequestId);
   // call helper method for validation
   var validationResult = ValidateRequest.Validate(request, response, ValidateOptions.All)  
   ...
}
```

But I don't want to write this line of code in every method:

```
var validationResult = Validate.ValidRequest(request, response, ValidateOptions.All)
```

**What is the best way to do this?**

PS. This is `Validate` method:

```
public static bool Validate(RequestBase request, ResponseBase response, ValidateOptions validate)
{
   //Validate Client Key. 
   // Hardcoded here.
   if ((Validate.ClientKey & validate) == Validate.ClientKey)
   {
      if (request.ClientKey != "ABC123")
      {
         response.Acknowledge = AcknowledgeType.Failure;
         response.Message = "Unknown Client Key";
         return false;
      }
   }    

   // Validate access token
   if ((Validate.AccessToken & validate) == Validate.AccessToken)
   {
      if (request.AccessToken != _accessToken)
      {
         response.Acknowledge = AcknowledgeType.Failure;
         response.Message = "Invalid or expired AccessToken. Call GetToken()";
         return false;
      }
   }

   // Validate user credentials
   if ((Validate.UserCredentials & validate) == Validate.UserCredentials)
   {
      if (_userName == null) 
      {
         response.Acknowledge = AcknowledgeType.Failure;
         response.Message = "Please login and provide user credentials before accessing these methods.";
         return false;
      }
   }

   return true;
}
```

One more question: Where is the best place to store `_accessToken`, `_userName` on server?

Comment: Take a look at message inspectors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks in your case no easy way to achieve what you want. In general you can do some custom things like security validation either on transport level or on WCF level. If your service is hosted in IIS, you can implement custom authentication module, but it's not your case, since security information is in data contracts. WCF also have several extensibility points, like custom endpoint behaviors, [Message Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) and mentioned by @trydis message inspectors. But they all are not suitable for you out of the box, since it can require taking care on messages serialization and other custom things.
Better is keep doing this in your code, and if you want to optimize your code, take a look at [postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use custom validation attributes and then apply the Validation Application Block from the Enterprise Library. Start with the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650484.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement and [plug a Message Inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx).

For an extended list of related use cases on Message validation, [take a look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649251.aspx). It will probably come in handy in the future.